# How to configure nosql db voldemort on windows 7

Tags: nosql, voldemort

I am new user to Voldemort db.

I am referring http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/quickstart.html
I followed the step one, I downloaded the archive and extracted it into "D:\Voldemort\".

On the second step, when i go to command prompt and type command

```
D:\Voldemort\voldemort-0.96>bin/voldemort-server.sh config/single_node_cluster
```

I get following error.

> 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Is there any step by step guide available on net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bin/voldemort-server.sh is a shell file in linux os. which can be executed in Linux only.
Error was, I was trying to run shell script in windows command prompt.

the link http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/quickstart.html gives the steps to run Voldemort nosql db in Linux.

if you want to run voldemort on windows .You will have to convert all shell scripts(.sh files) to batch file(.bat)

Comment: can you please post or provide your bat files?

Answer (score 1):

you can reference this blog:http://blog.netoearth.com/html/201107/how-to-install-voldemort-on-windows.htm

Here is bat files : https://gist.github.com/erikhoward/344463

voldemort-shell.bat：

```
@echo off

REM
REM   Copyright 2008-2009 LinkedIn, Inc
REM   Copyright 2010 Erik Howard http://www.gonosql.com http://erikhoward.net
REM
REM  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
REM   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
REM   You may obtain a copy of the License at
REM
REM      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
REM
REM  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
REM  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
REM  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
REM  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
REM  limitations under the License.
REM

set Count=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a Count+=1
if %Count% equ 2 goto :continue
echo USAGE: bin/voldemort-shell.bat store_name bootstrap_url [command_file]
goto :eof
:continue

setlocal
SET BASE_DIR=%~dp0..

%BASE_DIR%\bin\run-class.bat jline.ConsoleRunner voldemort.VoldemortClientShell %*

endlocal

:eof
```

https://gist.github.com/erikhoward/344450

run-class.bat:

@echo off

REM REM Copyright 2008-2009 LinkedIn, Inc REM Copyright 2010 Erik Howard http://www.gonosql.com http://erikhoward.net REM REM Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); REM you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. REM You may obtain a copy of the License at REM REM http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 REM REM Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software REM distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, REM WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. REM See the License for the specific language governing permissions and REM limitations under the License. REM

set Count=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a Count+=1
if %Count% gtr 1 goto :continue
echo %0 java-class-name [options]
goto :eof
:continue

```
SET BASE_DIR=%~dp0..
SET CLASSPATH=.

for %%j in (%BASE_DIR%\dist\*.jar) do (call :append_classpath "%%j")
for %%j in (%BASE_DIR%\lib\*.jar) do (call :append_classpath "%%j")
goto :run

:append_classpath
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%1
goto :eof

:run
REM You might have to adjust the max allowable memory setting to fit your environment
if "%VOLD_OPTS%" == "" set "VOLD_OPTS=-Xmx256M -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
java -Dlog4j.configuration=src/java/log4j.properties %VOLD_OPTS% -cp %CLASSPATH% %*

endlocal
:eof@echo off

REM
REM   Copyright 2008-2009 LinkedIn, Inc
REM   Copyright 2010 Erik Howard http://www.gonosql.com http://erikhoward.net
REM
REM  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
REM   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
REM   You may obtain a copy of the License at
REM
REM      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
REM
REM  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
REM  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
REM  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
REM  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
REM  limitations under the License.
REM

set Count=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a Count+=1
if %Count% gtr 1 goto :continue
echo %0 java-class-name [options]
goto :eof
:continue

SET BASE_DIR=%~dp0..
SET CLASSPATH=.

for %%j in (%BASE_DIR%\dist\*.jar) do (call :append_classpath "%%j")
for %%j in (%BASE_DIR%\lib\*.jar) do (call :append_classpath "%%j")
goto :run

:append_classpath
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%1
goto :eof

:run
REM You might have to adjust the max allowable memory setting to fit your environment
if "%VOLD_OPTS%" == "" set "VOLD_OPTS=-Xmx256M -server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
java -Dlog4j.configuration=src/java/log4j.properties %VOLD_OPTS% -cp %CLASSPATH% %*

endlocal
:eof
```